# How to build an anchor link to open page in new window using Kendo Grid Columns?

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, anchor

I have a Kendo Grid with a column definition as follows:

`columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title("ID #").Width("150px").ClientTemplate("#=showDetails(data.Id)#");`

I'm calling a method showdetails that returns a link to open the details in a new page.

I need some help figuring out how to build the link.

This is my showDetails method:

```
function showDetails(data) {

   var returnText = "<a href='/Detail/Index/" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";
   return returnText;
}
```

How do I modify it, so, the details page is opened in a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
target="_blank" to return statement 

var returnText = "gt a href='/Detail/Index/" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";
```

to:

```
var returnText = "gt a target='_blank' href='/Detail/Index/" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";
```

Reference link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: Thank's. I was trying to append it to the end and was doing something wrong with quotes. Apparently, it was much easier to add it in front, like it is in your example. :)